# Importing contacts into the GAL

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

I have a list of People and E-Mail addresses that my client would like to be able to download and then import into their GAL (Global Address List) in Outlook.  Right now it is in a DataGrid.  Several questions...

1. Is that possible?
2. What format do I need to put the list into so that it can be imported?
3. How do I import it?

I haven't been able to find out much on the topic, so cheers for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to look at this.

The GAL is basically driven from Active directory. So you can use the AD import tools.
or use the programing interface ADSI.

take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327620 for a tool and example
or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170(VS.85).aspx for ADSI.

Marcus